# CoreBluetooth: Running as Central and Peripheral at the same time

Tags: gamekit, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, peripherals

In GameKit I'm able to set up peer-to-peer connections. I'm wondering whether in iOS 6 I'll be able to achieve something similar with bluetooth low energy, i.e. having a Peripheral Manager advertising and a Central Manager scanning for peers at the same time.

Comment: Given that iOS 6.0 is still under NDA, all I can say is that you should watch videos of both Core Bluetooth sessions from WWDC 2012 (sessions 703 and 705). They answer your question in the first, and expand upon it in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no connection between GKSessions and Bluetooth LE, i.e GameKit doesn't look for updates in BLE status. This could have been a good thing to implement though, let's hope Apple gets their eyes open for it.